# vb.net read running Windows app and remove the windows app

Tags: vb.net

I hope everyone well.

I have a small issue with my program I would like to read the running windows apps without the windows default apps

[Here is the picture (I would like to remove those app which having a red line on the side)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDXtZ.jpg)

And here is my basic code for it

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each proc As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If proc.MainWindowTitle <> "" Then
            ImgList.Images.Add(Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(proc.MainModule.FileName))
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(proc.ProcessName, ImgList.Images.Count - 1)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(proc.MainModule.FileName)
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just one thing I want to quickly mention. Sometimes, some programs may have a "not so good' installer/uninstaller", thus, may change an association of a previous program so when the newer program, which shares the same file type association gets removed, can mess up the original program association. You may be trying to removed programs that are perfectly fine. You may already know this, but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Which are the `windows default apps` in my computers? You mean the executables that don't contain an Icon, the process doesn't have a Window Caption, both?

Comment: yes kind of I want to remove all windows default apps from that list